# Fourier summation with different orders

Tags: python

I am trying to run the following script. My intention was to get the output which will give one high intensity gauss in the middle followed by two small gauss on both side of the big one. It is a Fourier summation of all the y values taking different n values each time and plotting them against x. But somehow, I am not getting the desired result. Some help would be appreciated. the code-

```
from pylab import *

n = 6    
D = 6

x = linspace(-3, 3, 13000)    
y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]    
F = []

for i in range(1,n):
    F=sum((item*cos(2*pi*i*x/D)for item in y)) 

plot(x,F,'r')

show()
```

Comment: You are assigning `F` `n-1` times. Did you mean `F[i]=sum(...)` or `F.append(sum(...))`?

Comment: The summation should be like this- 
Y1*cos(2*pi*i1*x/D)  +  Y2*cos(2*pi*i2*x/D) +  Y3*cos(2*pi*i3*x/D) +  Y4*cos(2*pi*i4*x/D) +  Y5*cos(2*pi*i5*x/D)
It should do the procedure for all the x values.  And finally it should plot them against x. I am not sure which way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning `F` each time through the loop.  This might be your problem, since at the end of your loop `for i in range(1,n)` you have F as a number, and not as a *list* of numbers.

To create a list of `F` values, simply change `F = sum(....)` to `F.append(sum(...))` and you will end up with a list of values at the end.

Also please note that `range(1, n)` is the range from `1` to `n-1`.  This may or may not be what you desired.